# Tornado Sentry Integration

Tags: python, django, tornado, sentry

Are there any solutions around, for sending error reports from [`tornado`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) to [`sentry`](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry)? Or any similar error logging systems for tornado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard [Sentry client](https://www.getsentry.com/docs/python/) — [**Raven**](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python) does support Tornado.

The [Sentry DSN](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/index.html#the-sentry-dsn) matches:
`{PROTOCOL}://{PUBLIC_KEY}:{SECRET_KEY}@{HOST}/{PATH}{PROJECT_ID}`

> Note: Protocol may also contain transporter type: gevent+http, gevent+https, twisted+http, **tornado+http**

This basically means that it will use standard Sentry HTTP protocol, but using Tornado's [AsyncHTTPClient](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient) to perform the request.

Note however, that it does not (as of now) support HTTPS, only unencrypted HTTP.

Answer (score 4):

The support for tornado has been added to Raven in a fork at https://github.com/openlabs/raven

A detailed documentation on how to proceed for the same can be found at https://github.com/openlabs/raven/blob/master/docs/config/tornado.rst

Comment: It is now merged in the standard raven distribution. https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/commit/59c1f0e870718d6e13dcbfe313f3d4370b9554e6